# How to invoke streams from within a stream in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to output progress messages, while I download files and populate my database in my flutter app.

For this, I am using a StreamBuilder and a Stream that yields status message updates while performing work.

So far so good, but now I would like to show some details about the download progress in addition to my status messages. As far as I understand, I can wrap the download progress in another stream, but now I am a little stuck as to how I would invoke that stream from within my status updating stream.

The code looks like this right now:

```
  Stream<String> _upsertResult(context) async* {
    yield "Downloading Identifiers... (1/6)";
    await IdentifierService.downloadIdentifiers();
    yield "Upserting Identifiers... (2/6)";
    await IdentifierService.upsertIdentifiers();
    yield "Downloading Locations... (3/6)";
    await LocationService.downloadLocations();
    yield "Upserting Locations... (4/6)";
    await LocationService.upsertLocations();
    yield "Downloading Identifiables... (5/6)";
    await IdentifiableService.downloadIdentifiables();
    yield "Upserting Identifiables... (6/6)";
    await IdentifiableService.upsertIdentifiables();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CurtainInformationScreen()),
      );
    });
  }
```

Right now `downloadIdentifiers()` is implemented as a Future, but I could rewrite it as a Stream, in order to be able to yield download progress status updates.

I think I can listen to a new Stream I create and re-yield it in my _upsertResult Stream, but I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to my problem here, like waiting for the Stream to end, but re-yielding all results from the Stream as it runs.

Comment: check `yield*` which yields a multi value

Comment: perfect, thank you that is the answer I was looking for, can you post it as answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: write a self answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)'s advice and did it like this:

```
yield "Downloading Identifiers... (1/6)";
yield* IdentifierService.downloadIdentifiers();
```

as according to http://dart.goodev.org/articles/language/beyond-async#yield

> The yield* (pronounced yield-each) statement is designed to get around
>   this problem. The expression following yield* must denote another
>   (sub)sequence. What yield* does is to insert all the elements of the
>   subsequence into the sequence currently being constructed, as if we
>   had an individual yield for each element. We can rewrite our code
>   using yield-each as follows:

Then I can just `yield` inside `downloadIdentifiers` and the value will be handed through.